# End of file seen and there were open elements, and Unclosed element

Tags: html, syntax-error, element

I am editing a WordPress widget's HTML.

I copied directly from the original code adding social media links and 1 additional social media section, copied from the first section, and changed only the names and links.

Whenever I checked it I get the following errors:

1. End of file seen and there were open elements
2. Unclosed element

See enclosed image.

[HTML Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps7Bv.png)

Here is the code ( WordPress widget HTML do not require; Doctype, title, header, etc ):

```html
 <div class="ce-team">
    <figure>
        <img src="https://ourfightingspirit.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/anthony-headshot-small.png" alt="team">
    </figure>
    <h3>
        Anthony Gigante
    </h3>
    <h6 class="team-position">host</h6>
    <p>
        The stories you will hear are people like you and me who have overcome incredible obstacles, succeeded, and at the same time inspiring others.
    </p>
<div class="team-socials">
    <a href=" https://ourfightingspirit.com/staff/anthony-gigante"><i class="cl-icon-facebook"></i></a><a href="Facebook—https://www.facebook.com/OurFightingSpirit"><i class="cl-icon-instagram"></i></a>  
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/OurFightingSpirit"><i class="cl-icon-instagram"></i></a><a href="Instagram—https://www.instagram.com/ourfightingsprit/"><i class="cl-icon-youtube"></i></a>   
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCps0blZJBsefbHfxXRpTgvQ">
        <i class="cl-icon-you-tube"></i></a>
        </div>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Paula

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first DIV is missing closing, Putting the closing DIV tag at the end of the code should fix the problem.

```html
<div class="ce-team">
  <figure>
    <img
      src="https://ourfightingspirit.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/anthony-headshot-small.png"
      alt="team"
    />
  </figure>
  <h3>Anthony Gigante</h3>
  <h6 class="team-position">host</h6>
  <p>
    The stories you will hear are people like you and me who have overcome
    incredible obstacles, succeeded, and at the same time inspiring others.
  </p>
  <div class="team-socials">
    <a href=" https://ourfightingspirit.com/staff/anthony-gigante">
      <i class="cl-icon-facebook"></i
    ></a>
    <a href="Facebook—https://www.facebook.com/OurFightingSpirit">
      <i class="cl-icon-instagram"></i
    ></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/OurFightingSpirit">
      <i class="cl-icon-instagram"></i
    ></a>
    <a href="Instagram—https://www.instagram.com/ourfightingsprit/">
      <i class="cl-icon-youtube"></i
    ></a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCps0blZJBsefbHfxXRpTgvQ">
      <i class="cl-icon-you-tube"></i
    ></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But closing the DIV is a bit confusing, as there are two possibilities to close the div tag. If the first option doesn't work well, try the following code. This closes the DIV before the second DIV

```html
<div class="ce-team">
  <figure>
    <img
      src="https://ourfightingspirit.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/anthony-headshot-small.png"
      alt="team"
    />
  </figure>
  <h3>Anthony Gigante</h3>
  <h6 class="team-position">host</h6>
  <p>
    The stories you will hear are people like you and me who have overcome
    incredible obstacles, succeeded, and at the same time inspiring others.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="team-socials">
  <a href=" https://ourfightingspirit.com/staff/anthony-gigante">
    <i class="cl-icon-facebook"></i
  ></a>
  <a href="Facebook—https://www.facebook.com/OurFightingSpirit">
    <i class="cl-icon-instagram"></i
  ></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/OurFightingSpirit">
    <i class="cl-icon-instagram"></i
  ></a>
  <a href="Instagram—https://www.instagram.com/ourfightingsprit/">
    <i class="cl-icon-youtube"></i
  ></a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCps0blZJBsefbHfxXRpTgvQ">
    <i class="cl-icon-you-tube"></i
  ></a>
</div>
```